# Do I push the data from the method into the model in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vuejs and am querying data from a rest api, but in the methods section. I am wondering if am I supposed to push the data from Ajax method to the data model in order to do conditional rendering in the markup? If so, how do I do this correctly?

```js
new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                items: [],
                Title: ""
            },
            created: function() {
                this.getCurrentUser();
            },
            methods: {
                getCurrentUser: function() {
                    var root = 'https://example.com';
                    var headers = {
                        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

                    }
                    var vm = this;
                    var __REQUESTDIGEST = '';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: root + "_api/web/currentuser",
                        type: 'Get',
                        headers: headers,
                        success: function(data) {

                            vm.Title = data.d.Title;
                            console.log(vm.Title)
                            if (vm.Title == "Marks, Wendy" || "Adams, Todd") {
                                document.getElementById("admin").style.display = "block";
                            }else
                            
                            {
                             document.getElementById("admin").style.display = "none";

                            }


                        }

                    })

                },

             
            }
        })
```

```html
`<div id="#app">
 <span v-if="vm.Title=='bourg,wallace'">Hello!</span>
 </div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in the template, you don't have to preface it with `vm.Title` or `this.Title`.
2. you need to wrap the span in something with an id of "app", so that it will inject the data binding into the `el: #app`.

You can try below snippet, then check [Vue Guide for Data/Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) on how Vue Data/Methods work:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      items: [],
      Title: ""
  },
  created: function() {
  },
  methods: {
      getCurrentUser: function() {
          let root = 'https://example.com';
          let headers = {
              accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

          }
          let vm = this;
          let __REQUESTDIGEST = '';
          setTimeout(
              function(data) {
                  vm.Title = 'bourg,wallace'
              }
          , 1000)
      },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="getCurrentUser">Change User</button>
 <span v-if="Title=='bourg,wallace'">Hello!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this fixes my problem. I am querying data and assigning it a variable of vm.Title.   How do I check it in the markup?

Comment: @Vzupo, it does. check the snippet.

Comment: ok I changed my vars to let and it solves the issue, my version was already wrapped correctly. I just want the admin element to appear if the name matches.

Comment: is there a reason why I wouldn't have to push the returned data into the "model"? or why using "let" works better..just want understanding for better clarity

Comment: @Sphinx..can you answer above questions